# How to use form input(s) in calculations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, variables

I am putting together a survey-submitting website, and I am giving visitors the option of specifying the time and date of a particular event they created:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><%= text_field(:day,   "", placeholder: "DD")   %></td>
    <td><%= text_field(:month, "", placeholder: "MM")   %></td>
    <td><%= text_field(:year,  "", placeholder: "YYYY") %></td>

    <td><%= text_field(:hour, "", placeholder: "HH") %> : <%= text_field(:minute, "", placeholder: "MM") %> </td>
    <td><%= radio_button_tag(:ampm, "AM") %></td><td><%= label_tag(:ampm, "AM") %></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><%= radio_button_tag(:ampm, "PM") %></td><td><%= label_tag(:ampm, "PM") %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My Survey model has a :time_of_event attribute that holds a Time object which will represent the time specified by the user that fills out the form.  I intend to make use of Time.parse to create a Time object out of the 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:00' that the user specifies.

I have minimal experience using Rails forms - I can create basic text_field tags, and can save the input in those tags to a particular model's attribute upon submitting the form.

How (if at all) can I go about calculating the input in form fields, and save that calculated result to a model's attribute?

In other words, something that will probably end up looking like:

```
survey.time_of_event = Time.parse(form_params[:year] + '-' + form_params[:month] ...etc)
```

Comment: Like that? Or use a model callback, or a model creator service, or...

Comment: You should take a look at datetime_select: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/datetime_select

Comment: or some kind of js based datetime-picker i.e. http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: Thank you everyone for your suggestions - that's a good, solid amount of information to look into! I'll check those out and see what I can put together. Thanks again.